# How to get two or more matching tags in a xml file using regular expression

Tags: regex, xml

I need help on regular expression in the below xml code I want to extract values in two tags (title,price) at a time so that my output should look like

Output required:

```
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <price>30.00</price>
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <price>49.99</price>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
```

Right now I am using:

```
   ^\s*<title>.*</title>
```

this code is fetching only `<title>`

```
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
```

How to get two tags at a time? can some one help me

**XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
     <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
     <author>J K. Rowling</author>
     <year>2005</year>
     <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <author>Per Bothner</author>
      <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
      <author>James Linn</author>
      <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
<book category="WEB">
   <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
   <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: which regex tool/flavor/programming lang are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex wont match your given xml because you haven't handled attributes for `title` tag. You can use this regex to get both `title` and `price` tags with a single expression:

`^\s*<(title|price)[^>]*>(.*)<\/\1>`

[regex matching price tag example](https://regex101.com/r/zQ2uZ7/1)
[same regex matching title tag example](https://regex101.com/r/cF5bJ8/1)

Also you can get the tag-name and value using back-reference \1 and \2 to the captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

What is your environment? You can do this easily with grep on a unix-like command line:

```
grep -E "<(title|price)"
```

Comment: i will be using this in a tool, there i cant use grep command.